# Asterisk and sip station codecs

Tags: voip, asterisk

we have a small instance running on ec2 of 
voxilla/FreePBX-Asterisk-1.6.0.5-i386.manifest
which has been updated as far as i can see 

We signed up for sipstation (because it removes half the configuration headaches)

my problem is sipstation says it is using 
codec Priorities : ulaw | g729  

my thought is that if the phones (gxp2000) arent using the same codec then the asterisk box is having to encode all of the phone data (overloiading the tiny processor and killing call quality)

current setup is

```
# Preferred Vocoder
# 0 - PCMU, 2 - G.726-32, 3 - GSM, 4 - G.723.1, 8 - PCMA,
# 9 - G.722, 18 - G.729A/B, 98 - iLBC

 In order :
 0,8,4,18,2,98,9,3
```

which (both?)  should i change  and is my thought process corect on the quality

Comment: It also seems to stutter on the recordings (not cut out) but literally pause and then continue to play

Comment: Also Getting a severe stutter on recording playback...


http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3031623/call%20recording%20with%20LIGNov%2011%2C%202011%2014414%20PM.wav

the stutter is not always in the same place

this is the file I upload to "System Recordings"
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3031623/output.wav

I moved to EBS and that had no affect on this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right that the Asterisk box has to transcode the audio. I'd say try setting Asterisk and your phones to use GSM and see how it goes.

I'm guessing the G729 codec is what is causing the stutter. It requires more processing power that many phones cannot handle, especially if you're doing three way calling.

Comment: it shouldnt be affected by the phones because it is IVR and never gets to the phone ... hmmm

Answer (score 0):

- Check out 'sip show channelstats' to give you an idea of what is going on
- Make sure you aren't doing any call recording because that could kill your system
- Make sure firewalls aren't blocking any packets
- Make sure local bandwidth isn't being eaten up by a workstation streaming music, bittorrenting, etc..